# Cordova.js include in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, cordova

Incuding cordova.js in my visualforce page

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.BPMobile, 'BPMobile/cordova/cordova.js')}" />
```

Getting the following in chrome console:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://bpsbox-bp.cs10.force.com/BPMobile/BP_Community_Intro'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
>   'gap://ready'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

there is no cdn to load cordova.js over https://

also just including cordova like this does not work when running on iphone

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like it's loading cordova.js ok, but then cordova is trying to load gap://ready, which is causing it to throw the Mixed Content error. Not sure what the answer is, but I'll ping a couple of people.

Comment: Here is the snippet that seems to cause the problem:   
// Check if they've removed it from the DOM, and put it back if so.
    if (execIframe && execIframe.contentWindow) {
        execIframe.contentWindow.location = 'gap://ready';
    } else {
        execIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        execIframe.style.display = 'none';
        execIframe.src = 'gap://ready';
        document.body.appendChild(execIframe);
  }

Comment: Seems like it is trying to create a iframe element. Saw that the sample app adds the follow Content-security-policy meta tag:  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *"> added it to my visualforce page but getting error, seems like it is not allowed.